# creating a string from List and adding a newline

Tags: python, string, newline

I'm creating a string which is returned from the function. I need the string to list some values.

I have created a list which is joined at the end to make the complete string. I'm trying to add a new line on each iteration in the while loop the list is appended to.

```
while shiftAmount < 25: #Iterates through all 26 combinations producing a processed value each time.
    shiftAndStore(shiftAmount)
    shiftAmount = shiftAmount + 1
    stringshift = str(shiftAmount)
    outputCipherText.append("The Encoded / Decoded text on shift " + str((shiftAmount - 1)) + " is ")
    outputCipherText.append(str(''.join(completePlainText)) + " \n")
    completePlainText = []
output = [''.join(outputCipherText)]
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? looking at the output it shows the \n but doesn't execute it and make a new line.

Comment: What kind of object is outputCipherText?

Comment: @enrico.bacis: It looks like it's a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not printing a string but a list of strings. The line

```
output = [''.join(outputCipherText)]
```

is adding a single string to a list. That look useless to me, you can simply change it with:

```
output = ''.join(outputCipherText)
```

to obtain a string, and not a list containing only one string. After that change you can use `print output` and all the special characters will be *executed*, so the `\n` characters will be shown as newlines.

If you don't want to change your code, you have to print the string and not the list of strings:

```
print output[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong but i think you don't have to include this `outputCipherText.append(str(''.join(completePlainText)) + " \n")` and `completePlainText = []`. You can directly output the outputCipherText with newline after the loop with `output = '\n'.join(outputCipherText)` and call `print(output)`

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
    output.append(''.join(outputCipherText))
```

at the end of the while loop and remove the `output = [''.join(outputCipherText)]` folowing it.